# Let $n$ be a number such that $n>3$ and $n$ and $n+2$ are prime numbers. Show that $m=n+1$ is divisible by $6$.

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I started with the notion that if $n$ and $n+2$ are prime, then:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
n\mod{2}=1 \\
(n+2)\mod{2}=1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
From this I deduced that $(n+1)\mod{2}=0$. So I have that $2|(n+1)$.
How to show that $3|(n+1)$?

Comment: Hint: $n+1$ is even and neither $n$ nor $n+2$ are divisible by 3.

Comment: Then there must be $n\mod{3}=0$, so that $n\mod{3}=2$ and $(n+2)\mod{3}=1$ because they are prime but is it enough?

Comment: Answering your question directly: all sequences of three consecutive integers have a multiple of $3$ $$\{\color{red}{3k},3k+1,3k+2\} \\ \{3k+1,3k+2,\color{red}{3k+3}\} \\ \{3k+2,\color{red}{3k+3},3k+4\}$$

Now, you have $\{n,n+1,n+2\}$ and you know that both $n$ and $n+2$ are primes (therefore not multiples of $3$). Where is the multiple of $3$?

Comment: So $n+1$ must be the multiple of $3$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** :

Observe that, modulo $6$, a prime number greater than $3$ can only be congruent to $1$ or $5$. If both $n$ and $n+2$ are  (twin) primes, what can you deduce?

Comment: @PM2Ring: Right. I forgot to add this, as the O.P. already did. I've fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain why it can only be congruent to $1$ or $5$?

Comment: @mcas Consider the divisors of $6k, 6k+2, 6k+3, 6k+4$

Comment: Oh, I see! For $n$ I have to options: $n=6k+1$ and $n=6k+5$. If we go with the first one, then $n+2=6k+3$ thus not prime. So from the second option, we get $n+1=6k$. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If $n>3$, then

- $ n \equiv 0 \bmod 6 \implies $ $n$ not prime
- $ n \equiv 1 \bmod 6 \implies $ $n+2$ not prime
- $ n \equiv 2 \bmod 6 \implies $ $n$ not prime
- $ n \equiv 3 \bmod 6 \implies $ $n$ not prime
- $ n \equiv 4 \bmod 6 \implies $ $n$ not prime
- $ n \equiv 5 \bmod 6 \implies $ $n+1$ divisible by $6$

Comment: Thank you for this explicit explanation!